# forgot to set a password on my dell windows8 and now i can't use my laptop

Tags: windows-8

I was trying to fix my laptop and I was deleting all sorts of stuff in my DELL windows-8 laptop and I forgot to set a new password on my laptop. Now when I turn my laptop on, it asks for a password that I forgot to set. Does anyone know if I can fix this?

Comment: Try just hitting enter without entering a password.  I once purposely set a computer up that way, figuring unauthorized people would spend time trying to figure out what the password was because they would assume from the prompt that there was one.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the battery of your  Dell laptop then re-insert it, this will reset your laptop to the factory settings and your data in D drive won't be affected but some additive apps may delete. Now, after doing this start your laptop and it will work.
Another method is to use a password recovery disk but this doesn't work with Microsoft accounts and in windows 8 we use Microsoft account so try the method I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of tools that are easy to use for password reset. This is only for local password:

- [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/): assembles over 100 PC hardware diagnosis tools into one bootable CD to analyze and repair hard drives and boot problems.
- **OHPCrack**: a free Windows password cracker based on rainbow tables. It is a very efficient implementation of rainbow tables done by the inventors of the method. It comes with a Graphical User Interface and runs on multiple platforms.
- **Chntpw**: a small Windows password removal utility that can run from a CD or USB drive.

The tool needs some knowledge in computer so it is not ideal for beginner users. if you found the above suggestions not fit for you, then [this tutorial](http://www.uukeys.com/reset-windows-8-password-without-disk.html) may be a good bet as it has a nice user interface during the whole process. You only need to click the mouse.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.